# Error running MOE project in iOS Device

Tags: ios, libgdx, intel

Running MOE (Multi-OS Engine) samples in simulator work, but for iOS devices I'm getting this error, as well as running the command `./gradlew moeIpaBuild` in command line terminal.

> Error: MyProject has conflicting provisioning settings. MyProject is
>   automatically signed, but provisioning profile iOS Team Provisioning
>   Profile: * has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile
>   value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual
>   signing in the project editor.

```
###########
# ERROR LOG
###########

 FAILED
Build settings from command line:
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = 864F8FAE90E6FC935B7B379A6DBD77555B8660ED
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/path/to/the/samples/moe-project/moe/samples-java/LibGDXMissileCommand/ios/build/moe/xcodebuild/Debug-iphoneos
    DEVELOPMENT_TEAM = 53*******C
    DSTROOT = /Users/path/to/the/samples/moe/samples-java/LibGDXMissileCommand/ios/build/moe/xcodebuild/dst
    MOE_GRADLE_EXTERNAL_BUILD = YES
    OBJROOT = /Users/path/to/the/samples/moe/samples-java/LibGDXMissileCommand/ios/build/moe/xcodebuild/obj
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO
    PROVISIONING_PROFILE = ********-****-****-****-************
    SDKROOT = iphoneos10.2
    SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/path/to/the/samples/moe/samples-java/LibGDXMissileCommand/ios/build/moe/xcodebuild/shared_precomps
    SYMROOT = /Users/path/to/the/samples/moe/samples-java/LibGDXMissileCommand/ios/build/moe/xcodebuild/sym

=== BUILD TARGET LibGDXMissileCommand OF PROJECT LibGDXMissileCommand WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
LibGDXMissileCommand has conflicting provisioning settings. LibGDXMissileCommand is automatically signed, but provisioning profile iOS Team Provisioning Profile: * has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "Automatic" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ios:moeMainDebugIphoneosXcodeBuild'.
```

I only modified this part from `"buil.gradle"` in ios mudule:

```
moe {
    xcode {
        mainTarget 'LibGDXMissileCommand'
        companyIdentifier 'com.mycompany'
        packageName 'com.mycompany.MyApp'
        //infoPlistPath '' // Absolute path to Info.plist file. If this arg is not set new Info.plist will be generated.
        deploymentTarget '9.0'
        xcodeProjectDirPath 'xcode'
        generateProject false
    }
    signing {
        // String, ID of the development team.
        developmentTeam='53*******C'

        // String, path to the provisioning profile.
        provisioningProfile='/Users/myuser/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/********-****-****-****-************.mobileprovision'

        // String, name of the signing identity
        signingIdentity='86********************************ED'
    }
}
```

Where can I find `build settings editor` or how can I switch to manual signing in the project editor?

No need to say that developmentTeam, provisioningProfile and signingIdentity have been tested already for a regular Xcode project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open your Multi-OS Engine Xcode project, go to `Build Settings` and set team, signing and provisoring profile for release and debug version. If you set automatic provisoring, xcode try to find Distribution Provisoring profile with your app Bundle ID.

Sign in to developer.apple.com and make sure you have a **Distribution Provisoring profile** that match to your Bundle Identifier.

If you just created provisoring profile, go to **Xcode Preferences -> Accounts**, select your account/team and click View Details. In the dialog that appears, click the "Download all” button.